# How to resample/reorganize dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe.

```
 df1=pd.DataFrame({'user':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B'], 'status': 
 [1,0,1,0,1,0,1],'bindate':['2019-1-20','','2019-1-27','','2019-1- 
  2','','2019-1-25'],'unbindate':['','2019-1-25','','2019-1-30','','2019- 
 1-20','']})
```

It looks like this

```
  user   stutas  bindate      unbindate
0  A       1     2019-01-20   Nat
1  A       0     Nat          2019-01-25
2  A       1     2019-01-27   Nat
3  A       0     Nat          2019-01-30
4  B       1     2019-01-02   Nat
5  B       0     Nat          2019-01-20
6  B       1     2019-01-25   Nat
```

I want to use Pandas to come up with a new dataframe that looks like below

```
  user     bindate      unbindate
0  A       2019-01-20   2019-01-25
1  A       2019-01-27   2019-01-30
2  B       2019-01-02   2019-01-20
3  B       2019-01-25   None
```

Our server captures the date when user becomes the member as bindate, and captures the date when user exists the member as unbindate. If it is a member, status=1, else status=0

I want to mash the records to create a date range to show the user as a member. Notice user A binds and unbinds twice, so A is not the member in the end. User B binds twice, unbinds once, so B is the member in the end, hence I leave the unbindate as None.
I tried to use .loc to grab the data, no luck.
Is there a better way to achieve this? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quit efficient but work `groupby` `sorted` the value by `isnull`

```
df=df.mask(df=='Nat')
df.groupby('user').apply(lambda x : x.apply(lambda y : sorted(y,key=pd.isnull))).\
    dropna(subset=['bindate','unbindate'],thresh=1)
Out[64]: 
  user  stutas     bindate   unbindate
0    A       1  2019-01-20  2019-01-25
1    A       0  2019-01-27  2019-01-30
4    B       1  2019-01-02  2019-01-20
5    B       0  2019-01-25         NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You used a nested lambda expression, what does it do? Other than that, your way is working, since in the real world, the data is not sorted interleaved with one line being date the other being nan.

Comment: @LiuYu i am groupby by the user first , then for each group, I sorted the value by the key whether they are null or not , if they are null , they been shift down :-)

Comment: @LiuYu also  if this solved your problem , would you like upvote  and accept the answer ?

Comment: Just click the up arrow and the check mark? I just did. Thank you. I am actually confused by your nested lambda. It does work!

Comment: Mac is so hard? LOL. I feel the same way!

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe is exactly as you have shown with interleaved bind and unbind, `shift` could be enough:

```
df1['unbindate'] = df1.unbindate.shift(-1)
df1 = df1.loc[df1.status != 0].reset_index(drop=True).drop(columns='status')
```

It gives as expected:

```
  user    bindate  unbindate
0    A  2019-1-20  2019-1-25
1    A  2019-1-27  2019-1-30
2    B  2019-1-02  2019-1-20
3    B  2019-1-25        NaN
```

Comment: Thank you. Shift is the way to go. the original data is not really interleaved. But I order by user and bindate, it is now interleaved. You just made my day, Thank you.

Comment: Wait, I actually encountered a problem. When I order the dataframe. The bind and unbind don't work like a charm. All the nan's move to the end. So I cannot use shift. Any ideas to sort the data?